# Django SQL Windows Function with Group By

Tags: python, sql, django, mariadb

I have this MariaDB Query

```sql
SELECT 
    DAYOFWEEK(date) AS `week_day`, 
    SUM(revenue)/SUM(SUM(revenue)) OVER () AS `rev_share` FROM orders
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(completed)
```

It will result in a table which show the revenue share.

My goal is to archive the same with the help of Django's ORM layer.

---

I tried the following by using RawSQL:

```py
share = Orders.objects.values(week_day=ExtractIsoWeekDay('date')) \
    .annotate(revenue_share=RawSQL('SUM(revenue)/SUM(SUM(revenue)) over ()'))
```

This results in a single value without a group by. The query which is executed:

```sql
SELECT 
    WEEKDAY(`orders`.`date`) + 1 AS `week_day`,
    (SUM(revenue)/SUM(SUM(revenue)) over ()) AS `revenue_share`
FROM `orders`
```

And also this by using the Window function:

```py
share = Orders.objects.values(week_day=ExtractIsoWeekDay('date')) \
    .annotate(revenue_share=Sum('revenue')/Window(Sum('revenue')))
```

Which results into the following query

```sql
SELECT 
    WEEKDAY(`order`.`date`) + 1 AS `week_day`, 
    (SUM(`order`.`revenue`) / SUM(`order`.`revenue`) OVER ()) AS `rev_share` 
FROM `order` GROUP BY WEEKDAY(`order`.`date`) + 1 ORDER BY NULL
```

But the data is completely wrong. It looks like the Window is not using the whole table.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is.

Comment: Thx @GordonLinoff for pointing that out. I was a little bit too frustrated with that problem.